# php javascript download .gz file ajax

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

In my project I am using Symfony 3 + [Filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) and I need to download a .gz file. I do ajax request to my server with the following code:

```
function requestAjax(json_data) {
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax'
    , method: 'post'
    , data: json_data
  });
  return request;
}

var json_text = {'type': 'download_file'};
var request = requestAjax(json_text);
request.done(function (response) {
    var blob = new Blob(
        [response], {
        type: "text/plain;charset=" + document.characterSet});
        saveAs(blob, 'filename.gz');
    });
```

On php side I do the following:

```
$myfile = '/opt/myfile.gz';
$fp = fopen($myfile, "rb");
$response = base64_encode(fread($fp, filesize($myfile)));
fclose($fp);
return new Response($response);
```

But when I try to open my downloaded file, I get an error that the file is broken and cannot be read (still I can read it on my server and I know that the file is ok). So the question is how to download a `.gz` file with an ajax call in php + javascript. Thank you.

Comment: `type: "text/plain;charset=" + document.characterSet});` — For a gzip file?!

Comment: By the way, in symfony you should return an instance of BinaryFileResponse.

Comment: which type should be used?